# How to increase the speed of a video to 1.05x without changing the frequency of the video sound?

Tags: windows, video

I'm looking forward to increase the speed of a video clip to `1.05x` without changing the frequency of the video sound using a simple windows software. I googled, but I couldn't find anything to do this. Actually, every software I saw, increases the speed to something like `1.5x`, `2.0x`, `2.5x`, ... . Thanks for sharing your experience.

Comment: I am not aware of any software which can do this in one step, but you can surely solve this by separating the audio tracks first from the video stream, use Audacity to change the audio (without changing pitch, see https://www.lifewire.com/audacity-tutorial-change-songs-speed-without-affecting-pitch-2438167), use your favorite video stream changer and mux the result together afterwards.

Comment: ... another approach might be ffmpeg, if a command line tool is ok for your: see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video   I did not try it out by myself, however.

Answer (score 3):

[image: kdenlive speed test]

The image above was just captured from my test of [kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/download/) for windows. I had attempted the same process on my linux box, but the screen configuration is different and I was not able to locate the parameter setting for speed. I could easily add the effect, but not adjust it.

In the windows version, everything fell into place. I watched about a minute of [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSqv8Z9IMg0) regarding adding the effect, but had already accomplished what the video showed.

My test allowed me to change the speed in single digit increments, although I did not test decimal increments. My tests allowed 105 percent, 121 percent, 33 percent (triple length, 1/3rd speed!) and a couple others.

I think you may find this will do what you require, including changing the speed of the audio. This particular test was interesting to hear, at 121 percent. The pitch was higher, but easily understood.

I think I screwed up the answer by not reading thoroughly the question, and overlooking the "without changing the frequency of the video sound."

To that end, I've located a resource that purports to provide adjustment of speed of an audio clip without changing the frequency. I think it's probably more accurate to say that it changes the speed and restores the frequency or pitch of the audio, but that resource is [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) and the instructions are on [this page.](https://www.lifewire.com/audacity-tutorial-change-songs-speed-without-affecting-pitch-2438167)

The instructions are relatively simple. 
Use File, Open to load the existing audio clip. *My note: Audacity will read some video formats directly and use only the audio.*
Click Effect, Change Tempo.

Use the sliders and the preview button to accomplish the desired speed, File, Save (or Save As) to export the modified audio.

[image: Audacity Tempo Change]

Comment: It might be worth editing this answer to include: Price: _gratis_, Licence: _GPL_ & Platform: _Win, OS-X & Linux_.

Comment: Does this software change the frequency of the video sound when I speed up the video?

Comment: When I did my test, as noted in the answer, the pitch went up, but could still be understood. That was at 121 percent increased speed. You have to split the audio and video in order to get audio increase, but that's one extra click, no other complications.

Comment: If I speed up the video without its sound, they don't match together anymore. If you see some player such as `pot` player, we can speed up the video without changing the pitch. I know I can split the sound and video, but actually I want to know is there a movie editor to increase the speed of a video without changing the frequency of the sound?